# What is the difference between these two methods of wrtiing using the webapp2 framework

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

What is the difference between these two methods of writing to a webapp front page?

```
self.response.write('method 1')
```

and

```
self.write('method 2')
```

Answer (score 1):

self.write is not a webapp / webapp2 method. self.write looks like a tornado.web.RequestHandler method.

In webapp2 self.response.wite() .write() a method of the response object [for building a response](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html).
You can also use `response.write()` like this:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, request, response):
        response.write("<html><body><p>Hi there!</p></body></html>")
```